# PHP thumbnails for urls - physical storage or not and options

Tags: php, url, thumbnails

I am creating a PHP thumbnail app for links. I am considering to options:

1. **Store image** - and since I dont want to create new image everytime user shares the same link I would like to store the images with names referencing the url,
   I also want to avoid too-long file names if someone enters very long url. So I was thinking about hashing the url,
   but is `md5()` enaugh? Or should I use `sha1()` (8 characters more = 40),
   or does anyone else have a better idea how to store it ?
2. **Save just a link and image link** - which raises another choices - store it in DB
    or as a files with name > as in 1. < containing only the link?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to be short you can use uniqid() function, and it's better if you save it in the DB yes.

Comment: @JorgeFaianca and what about performance? and storage? It seems to me that I would have to do another query for DB - and is DB entry larger/smaller than file name+content?

Comment: Performance while will be no problem if you only want that, and it should be faster than reading files.

Comment: @JorgeFaianca well sorry but should is not good enaugh for me :) no offense, anyway I think that comunicating with DB is comunicating with another running app, on the other hand reading a file is a system action.

Comment: Ok, DB will be faster than reading from a file. i took the should off :P

Comment: @JorgeFaianca ok :D and have you considered my last comment (not this one, the one before)

Comment: Yes i did, and i did understand your point, but to answer to your real question, i was just stating that DB will be faster and way more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating virtual filesystems, I use `sha1()` even though collisions are fairly unlikely with `md5()`, it doesn't cost much more.

As for storing the thumbnails, I would recommend saving them to disk once they're creating.  The method of detecting that you've already created the thumbnail vs. it being a first-time request will depend on how you're creating and storing them.

In one of my applications, users upload files which I store using the SHA1 hash onto the filesystem with the metadata in a MySQL DB.  The file is retrieved using three parameters: file_id, width, and height.  I retrieve the SHA1 hash from the DB for the specified file_id, then check the filesystem for the existence of a file named [hash]*[width]*[height].  If it doesn't exist, then I generate the thumbnail and serve it up.  If it does exist, then this means I've already created the thumbnail of this size and I serve it up.

Since I'm using a script to generate/send the thumbnail on-demand, my script that serves the file checks for a last-modified from the client and tells the client to use its cached version, as appropriate, rather than spending bandwidth to re-send the same image.

Comment: Ok your answer contained even some extra info I already know, but thanks, I think other may find it useful. I personally would recommend that the script would return url with the last modified value as int get parametr "v" -  `<img src="http://mydomain.com/hashhash?v=54151">`

Comment: Do you have any experience with large amount of thumbnails - I mean the overall size on disk? some ratio of numberOfUrls:KBsize?

Comment: Yes, thumbnails tend to be rather small, usually under 20KB. The structure of the filesystems I've built have been setup to handle billions of files (should the need arise). I do this by nesting directories such that I have a root `files/` directory, which contains directories `00/` through `ff/`, which themselves contain the same set. So a thumbnail with a hash of `42c63e3229088aae80e28226c96fdf2a5e203cc1` is stored at `files/42/c6/42c63e3229088aae80e28226c96fdf2a5e203cc1`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an url outside the document root and call the image with a script. If the user has an url associated in the database the script will call this url. E.g.

```
 <img src="script.php" />
```

Comment: Of course I will do something similar, but the question is about whether to store thumb image physically or not - and aditional choices for both ... - do you understand now ? :)

Comment: I would store the url (relative) in the database and the image in a directory outside the document root (not in the database).